# Change element class depending upon the position of the element

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have some problem with this. Hope u can help me.

I created the menu in the fixed position. I would like it to change the color on some sections of my website.

Please look attachment to better understand
[image: Solution image]

Actually I have some code:

My toggle menu:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="input-toggler">   

<label for="toggle" class="menu-toggler">

        <span class="menu-toggler-line" id="change"></span>
        <span class="menu-toggler-line" id="change"></span>
        <span class="menu-toggler-line" id="change"></span>

</label>
```

Style for this menu:

```
.menu-toggler{
    position: fixed; 
    right:5%; 
    top:10%;
    z-index: 9999; 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content:center; 
    flex-direction:column; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggler-line{
    height: 4px;
    width: 32px;
    display: block;
    background-color: $font--color;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    transition: transform .2s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
```

And unfortunately I can't write any meaningful jquery code to handle this solution ...

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: There are a lot of examples on the net which can help you. You'll need to find the vertical position of the menu, and the vertical position of the elements you scroll over. When they overlap, change the style.

Comment: I can't find the right track ... Have you some examples?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question again?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that allows me to change the color of my menu when scrolling when it overlaps some other element. I would like my menu to change color only on this section... I am looking for something that will lead me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this code:

```js
var nav = $("#navbar").offset();
var $contentDivs = $(".division");
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $contentDivs.each(function(k) {
        var _thisOffset = $(this).offset();
        var _actPosition = _thisOffset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
        if (_actPosition < nav.top && _actPosition + $(this).height() > 0) {
            $("#navbar").removeClass("light dark").addClass($(this).hasClass("light") ? "light" : "dark");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    right:20px;
    height:100px;
}
#navbar.light {
    color:black;
}
#navbar.dark {
    color:white;
}
.division {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    height:350px;
}
.division.dark {
    background:black;
}
.division.light {
    background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ecdc7512a9.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   
<div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <i class="fa fa-bars  fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <span id="current"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
</div>
```